# Protractor - how to check that all instance of a class is not present in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I need to check whether all elements of a class are not present in the DOM. Say, I want all the elements with the class `.loading` to not present in the DOM.  I know I can do this:

```
browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf($$('.loading')), 5000);
```

My question is whether this code will wait for all the `loading` class to go away or just the first one? If it waits for only the first one, how will I make it work for all of them? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this should wait until ALL elements matching the locator are not present

But for future, when in doubt, you can write your function instead of using `ExtectedConditions` library. In this case, you could do

```
let loading = $$('.loading');
await browser.wait(
  async () => (await loading.count()) === 0, 
  5000, 
  `message on failure`
);
```

In fact, this is what I'm using to handle multiple loading animations ;-)

Comment: let me know if you want me to explain how the function works

Comment: Thanks @volun_tear. What is the benefit of using your own function instead of ExtectedConditions?

Comment: just as you asked you were not sure how ExpectedCondition was working behind scene, so we wrote our own function. Also if you're comfortable coding, you can create any waiting conditions with no limits. Some that I've done are, wait until there are more than 3 elements matching locator; wait until there are 2 browser tabs are open, wait until element's attribute has substring. You could also do wait until multiple conditions are satisfied. so again, no limits, except for imagination